# Thinking_Sphinx Partial Work Matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, indexing, thinking-sphinx

I have a rails app with thinking_sphinx successfully working for indexing/searching. I was, however, wondering if there was a way to get partial work matches to search. Meaning if I have a report with title "Best Report" and I searched "Best" it would return that report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it working this way by default, however you can look into match modes here http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you to try the Wildcard search with Thinking Sphinx.

There are basically three settings that rule the wildcard search world: * enable_star *     min_prefix_len * min_infix_len

- min_prefix_len =>  Minimum word prefix length to index
- min_infix_len => Infix indexing allows to implement wildcard
  searching by 'start*','*end', and '*middle*' wildcards

Note:  *enabled_star is required plus one of the other two for settings for enabling either prefix or infix search (can't have both, at least on the same index)*

For Example :

Model :

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

   #define the indexes for your searchable attributes 

  define_index do
   indexes :comment
   enable_star: true
   min_infix_len: 3
   has created_at,updated_at
  end

end
```

Controller :

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController

     def search
      @result = ThinkingSphinx.search "*#{params[:id]}*" ,:classes => [Comment,....] 

     end
    end
```

Then Rebuild the thinking_sphinx  :

1. rake ts:stop
2. rake ts:index
3. rake ts:start

(or)

1. rake ts:rebuild

the above example will result following instances :

- Comment.search "Best*"
- Comment.search "Best Rep* "
- Comment.search    "*Rep* " .. etc

If any queries feel free, please ask me .......